# display custom media folders to wordpress media popup

Tags: custom-field, uploads, media

I have plugin "Maxgalleria Media Library Plus" in my wordpress site, where I can organize my images in different folders.When I look via FTP, in the uploads directory there are all folders I have created. But it doesn't allow me do display images in directories or filter by directory.

I wonder how can I add it to wordpress media library popup in posts. Or Is there a way to add custom filter in that part of wordpress. I have made a lot of research, but I didn't find what I want.
I can upload my files in the different directories, but I can't display the images with the directory hierarchy,, in the media popup window to add media to post.

I also found the other plugin "WP media files" but it doesn't work with folders, it creates a category, but I don't need to do it with categories. Any ideas? Maybe someone has already done it?

Comment: I think these to plugins itself or their source code can help you: [custom upload dir](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir) ,  [enhanced media library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library)

Comment: Question is not clear.?  Are you expecting to show the folders in media library or you want to upload your images in different directory?

Comment: @Kvvaradha, Ok , I can upload my files in the different directories, but I can't display the images with the directory hierarchy, in the media popup window to add media to post. I don't now how to change the default popup media window and its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In media library,  the images are listed using mysql query which retrieves from your posts table.  So it won't display the folders and sub folders in it.  You can create categories and taxonomies to maintain it.  If you wish to use plugins.  Try some media management plugins.  I can suggest you.  `enhanced media library, media file manager,  media folder` are few plugins. You may try anyone. Google it for more plugins.

Comment: Actually I have lot of images in custom directories, and it will be very hard to transfer them to categories again. That is why I don't want to use plugins. I wonder if I can get folder hierarchy, and order them by images url folder param.